# Modify the contents of child divs inside another div using JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="abc">
    <div id="a_b"> abcd </div>
    <div id="c_d"> xyz </div>
</div>
```

Problem is the divs are dynamically generated and their IDs keep changing every time the page is rendered. On window load, the contents of `a_b` and `c_d` has to be passed a function `func()` and the output should be placed within the same div. How can I grab each child of div `abc` and modify their contents?

Comment: Is the `#abc` div always available?

Comment: Yes #abc is always available @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Then use children() of that.

Comment: `$("#abc").children()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.text()` along with `.each()` to achieve what you want.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#abc > div").each(function() {
     $(this).text(someFunction($(this).text()));
  });
});
```

Or the better code would be using the receiver function of `.text()`,

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#abc > div").text(function(_,v) {
    return someFunc(v);
  });
});
```

Comment: @R.S.K Yeah, That depends on what you are doing inside `someFunc`. If you have to deal with html elements, then `.html()` would be the right choice. :)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `#abc` div is always available, you can select that and then any direct child `div` element and loop over them by using `text()` with a handler function, like this:

```js
$('#abc > div').text(function(i, v) {
    return v + ' foobar';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc">
  <div id="a_b">abcd</div>
  <div id="c_d">xyz</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can create an array of the content of the child divs and pass that to your `func()`:

```
var textContents = $('#abc > div').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

func(textContents);

function func(arrText) {
    console.log(arrText); // = [ 'abcd', 'xyz' ]
}
```

Comment: Callback in `.text()` ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan why are you iterating over the elements on top of `.text(functi...` ?? Because the callback function would take care of iterating over all element's text one by one.  Am I guessing anything wrong?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Wow! Never thought it that way :)